# TeamCity build status parameter

Tags: parameters, teamcity-8.0

I may be overlooking a built in parameter in TeamCity.. I'm trying to send the build status as a parameter to a console application. The console application is a build step that needs to run even if previous steps have failed. If previous steps failed it will do one thing, and if the previous steps are successful it will do another.

I have the console app set up to take a build status parameter, but I'm not finding a built in build status parameter to use (Success/Failure). Am I missing something easy? How can I access the build status?

Thanks!

Comment: Please watch/vote for [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17975) about that.

Answer (score 8):

I've had to do a similar thing in the past and didn't manage to find a built in property that I could inject to pass the status.

In the end I used service messages in a previous build step to pass parameters into the subsequent step - printing out a message like `##teamcity[setParameter name='build.state' value='ok']` can be used to create a build property to thread state from one step to another.

I've seen someone take an approach of using the TeamCity REST API to query the status of the running build from a build step, but the prior approach was simple enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the solution found here:

http://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/get-teamcity-build-status-from-powershell/

I just created the same logic in C# in my console app to get the build status.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the code in the [link in the answer by user2097151](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/get-teamcity-build-status-from-powershell/), but it did not work at first. So I modified it. I will post the modifications here:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;

$buildId = "%teamcity.build.id%"
function TeamCityBuildStatus
{
    param
    (
        [string] $ServerUrl,
        [string] $UserName,
        [string] $Password,
        [string] $BuildId
    )

        $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

        $pair = "$($UserName):$Password"
        $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
        $client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $encodedCreds")

        $url = "https://$ServerUrl/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/$buildId/status"

        $status = $client.DownloadString($url)

        return $status -eq "SUCCESS"
}

$status = TeamCityBuildStatus -ServerUrl $teamcityUrl -UserName $teamcityUser -Password $teamcityPass -BuildId $buildId
```

This solution dose not relay in this being the last build.

The way I send the credentials I found it in [this](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000078404-Super-User-API-Access) thread.
And the TLS version change I found it in [this](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/is-it-possible-to-enable-tls-1-2-as-default-in-powershell/) thread.

Hope it helps someone.